# Problem trying to install iftop via Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, unix

I got Homebrew installed, but:

```
>brew install iftop
==> Downloading http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/download/iftop-0.17.tar.gz
File already downloaded in /Volumes/0/z/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> ./configure --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/iftop/0.17 --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/iftop/0.17/share/man
==> make install
ln: iftop: Permission denied
Error: The linking step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link iftop'
Warning: /usr/local/sbin is not in your PATH
You can amend this by altering your ~/.bashrc file
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/iftop/0.17: 7 files, 116K, built in 3 seconds
```

FYI, `~/.bashrc` does not exist, and

```
>$PATH
-bash: /Volumes/0/z/android:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory
```

What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: I fixed this by chowning all the folders in `/usr/local`

Comment: Does `brew doctor` give back any problems? Also the fact you have permission issues is worth looking in to.

Comment: That package isn't failing for several people here. Have you isolated what is different on your setup? Is this still a problem that you haven't solved?

Answer (score 5):

You can remedy things in your current shell by doing:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/sbin
brew link iftop
```

That'll get you past the warnings and let Homebrew install the iftop package. If the iftop package is installing things in to `/usr/local/sbin` that you're looking to run, you'll need to ensure this is on your `$PATH` when you open a shell. To do this, edit `~/.bash_profile` and add the line:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/sbin
```

To the end of the file to prepend `/usr/local/sbin` to each new shell you open.

Comment: I got it running by fixing permissions ... but is there any way to run `iftop` without `sudo`? Without `sudo` I get: `Permission denied` (I want to use this with GeekTool) Thanks!

Comment: Nope. Binding to a network interface is a privileged action. Only super users can do that.

Comment: Ah ... so no way to make it a Geeklet?

Comment: Well... You could make your own script that gets run by a root cronjob, and puts the relevant data into a text file every minute. Then you could get geektool to read the file every minute... To create a root crontab, you just run `sudo crontab -e`. Everything you put in there will run with root permissions.

Comment: iftop doesn't seem like the kind of program that could be run in geektool anyway. It needs to output static text, but it appears to run dynamically in curses.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using:

```
$ brew link iftop
```

As the message recommended? Otherwise it's likely you need to be su to successfully create the symlink. Try:

```
$ ./configure --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/iftop/0.17 --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/iftop/0.17/share/man
$ sudo make install
```