# How to install IFTOP the right way?

Tags: homebrew

I want to install IFTOP using Brew. However whenever I do it, I need to link it. The instructions given online doesn't work. It seems I need to type a PATH:(something here) every time before using IFTOP.

I'm using a 15-inch Retina Macbook Pro Late 2013. Can someone help me? I always keep my laptop updated to the latest. I don't use beta updates, if that helps.

Let me know how you can help me.

First instructions: http://macappstore.org/iftop/
Second instructions: [Problem trying to install iftop via Homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46531/problem-trying-to-install-iftop-via-homebrew)

For the second instruction, export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/sbin
command has to be ran every time. Even saving to a document and linking it (as told in that link) does not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

/usr/local/sbin is not in your user's PATH variable. The most simple method is adding the path /usr/local/sbin to the file /private/etc/paths:

```
sudo nano /private/etc/paths
```

Modify:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

to

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

and save the file to disk with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and  <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>. Then exit the shell or restart Terminal. This will change the PATH for all users.

If you want to restrict it to your user create and/or edit the file ~/.bash_profile with nano and add the line:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Save the file to disk with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and  <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>. Then exit the shell or restart Terminal. This will change the PATH for your user only.

---

To install iftop with brew from scratch in High Sierra with prerequisites (Xcode | Xcode Command Line Tools) already installed , open Terminal.app and enter:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew analytics off #optional
brew doctor #optional
brew install iftop
```

and add the /usr/local/sbin to the PATH as described earlier.

Comment: If you could add that as an answer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46531/problem-trying-to-install-iftop-via-homebrew I could close this one here as a duplicate.

Comment: @patrix The old question and answers are somehow outdated. No make etc necessary now.

Comment: Both Q are about installing iftop through homebrew

Comment: FANTASTIC, it works! I suggest to leave this open as I have never seen such an answer before.